# Upgrading to AEM 6.3

Tags: aem

I just upgraded AEM from version 6.2 to Version 6.3. I see a folder called archived-versions created under crx-quickstart. Is it safe to delete the contents inside that folder?

Answer (score 2):

I found a reference to `archived-versions` in an older upgrade documentation.

> Note that your existing crx-quickstart/bin/ will be archived below crx-quickstart/**archived-versions**/. The precise path is given in the output of the above java -jar command. If you have customized any of the scripts in this directory, you can find those changed files in the archive.

https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/deploying/upgrading.html

From what I can tell it's safe to delete unless you've made modifications to start up scripts you may wish to keep.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe moving all the content to a new AEM 6.3 instance instead of upgrading it is a better solution. This is usually what Adobe does with its AMS service.